# Scatterplot based on 2 categorical variables using ggvis package in R

Tags: r, plot, ggvis

[image]

I need to get a scatter plot like this based on 2 categorical variables where each variable has 2 levels.
I am using ggvis package in R.

This is my code so far

```
 salab<- read.table("http://users.stat.ufl.edu
/~rrandles/sta4210/Rclassnotes/data/textdatasets/KutnerData/
Chapter%2022%20Data%20Sets/CH22TA06.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")


    salab %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V1, fill = ~factor(V3*V4)) %>% layer_points()
```

[image]

Which is incorrect because i need 4 factors combinations. Can anyone help me to figure out what modification should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `factor(V3):factor(V4)` instead of `factor(V3*V4)`:

```
salab %>% 
  ggvis(~V2, ~V1, fill = ~ factor(V3):factor(V4)) %>% 
  layer_points()
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
salab$`V3*V4`<-paste0("V3=",salab$V3,"*","V4=",salab$V4)
salab %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V1, shape = ~`V3*V4`)  %>% layer_points()
```

[image]